# Import object in class using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am new to Javascript and TypeScript and I am wondering if it is possible to do some kind of dependency injection (maybe using require.js)

I have two classes in same module

```
module MyWebApp {
    export class ViewRouter {
           ... some class methods
    }
}

module MyWebApp {
    export class MyViewModel{
        private router: ViewRouter;

        constructor(router:ViewRouter router) {
           this.router = router;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I need MyViewModel I have to instantiate ViewRouter
`var vm = new MyViewModel(new ViewRouter());`

Is there any way around this? I thought that Require.js could help me solve my problem but I don't know how to use it with TypeScript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *new* instance *every time* you should probably do:

```
class MyViewModel{
    private router: ViewRouter;

    constructor() {
       this.router = new ViewRouter();
    }
}
```

Now if you want a "single" *shared* instance you can do:

```
module MyWebApp {
    export class ViewRouter {
           ... some class methods
    }

    export var router = new ViewRouter();       
}
```

and use `router`

Using RequireJS can do the same thing for your, but the principal idea will not change there. RequireJS is not an IOC container.

There are bunch of javascript IOC containers out there and I don't have a recommendation on that : [Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+ioc+container&oq=javascript+ioc+container&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)